# Ideas to secure PLSQL script

Tags: security, plsql

I've been using the wrap utility but it appears it's laughably easy to decode to get the source so I'm looking at alternatives.

- Is there something better than wrap?
- Is it possible to keep the source local and execute it on a remote machine?  I can connect to it via SSH/telnet

Comment: Don't let people access the database directly, then they can't view the source code.

Comment: Can you add some information on why you need to secure your code?  There might be some extreme measures to improve things but they may not be worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

With newer version or Oracle (11, 12) wrapper has been improved (but is not perfect). In my opinion it is the best option for reasonable size of code base.

You may send anonymous PLSQL blocks through the encrypted channel, however during parse your SQL will be present in Oracle memory or even visible in v$sqlarea.

You may call java or C from PLSQL, however they may be also not safe (jad, gdb).

You may call your socket, your rest service from PLSQL, than your code is safe.

Possibly attaching a specialized hardware will be secure but more expensive, and it is probably not the solution you are looking for.
Oracle Database Vault may be the option, but I am not familiar with it.

When the DB is in the hands of determined hacker you are lost, unless you put your code in your server.